# My mongoDB api is getting a webtask.io token error

Tags: mongodb, rest

I'm learning about webtask.io and so I've coded a simple REST api (I'm not using Express.js here but maybe I should). It's a little webtask.io app that connects to an mlab MongoDB database and retrieves todos from a tasklist collection. The issue is that I'm getting this error:

{"code":404,"message":"**unable to resolve jtn to webtask token**","req_id":"1504385487318.83712"}"

Any idea how to fix this error? Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
...
module.exports = 
  function (ctx, req, res) {
    // write the header and set the response type as a json
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    MongoClient.connect(ctx.data.MONGO_URL, function (err, db) {
     if (err) {
        res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(ERROR_RESPONSE.CONNECT_ERROR));
     } else {
      switch(req.method) {
       case 'GET':
        db.collection('tasklist').find({}).sort({"dateAdded" : -1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
         if (err) {
            res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(ERROR_RESPONSE.GET_ERROR));
         } else {
           res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
         }
         }); //toArray   

        break;
       //post, delete, and put are in here
      } //switch
    } //else no error 
    db.close();
    }); //Mongo connect
    res.end(); 
  } //export function
```

Comment: How old is your token?

Comment: It's a few days old, and I got it at https://webtask.io/token.  Can you give me some direction about how to set it up and specify it in a url, say key=value?  It's very long and cumbersome to carry around.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try using Express and now I'm able to run my little webtask.io without having to have a web token. I'm not sure why my first try required one and if I find that answer I will post it. Here is my working version:

```
/* express app as a webtask */
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Express = require('express');
var wt = require('webtask-tools');
var app = Express();
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

app.use(require('body-parser').json());

function doCRUD (crudType,req,res) {
  MongoClient.connect(req.webtaskContext.secrets.MONGO_URL,function (err, db) { 
     if (err) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
     } else {
       switch(crudType) {
        case 'GET':
         db.collection('tasklist').find({}).sort({"dateAdded" : -1}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
         if (err) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
         } else {
           res.end(JSON.stringify(docs));
         }
         }); //toArray   
         break;
        case 'POST':
         db.collection('tasklist').insertOne({"tasklist" :  req.query.todo, "dateAdded" : new Date()}, function(err, r) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
         });
         break;
        case 'DELETE':
         db.collection('tasklist').deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(req.query.id)},function(err){assert.equal(null,err)});
         break;
        case 'PUT':
        //not implemented for this hack
        break;
       }  
     }
 });
}
// GET
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  doCRUD('GET',req,res);
});
// POST
app.post('*', function (req, res) {
  doCRUD('POST',req,res);
  res.end();
});
// DELETE
app.delete('*', function (req, res) {
  doCRUD('DELETE',req,res);
  res.end();
});

// expose this express app as a webtask-compatible function*/

module.exports = wt.fromExpress(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if you do not specify a valid path.

Try this one for example :
https://wt-666ohgod666ohgod666ohgod666ohgod-0.run.webtask.io/antidisestablishmentarianism666